# "brew services restart mongodb-community" throws a status of error under brew services list. What is this error?

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I recently completed the m001 basics course on Mongo University and connecting to Atlas with the connection string was not a problem. With experimenting I messed up and now I am not able to start mongo. The steps I followed are (from my root directory):

1. `brew doctor --verbose`

to make sure Homebrew is running correctly and there were no issues.

**HomeBrew version**: *3.0.1*,

**macOs**: *11.1*,

**Homebrew Cask Staging Location**: */usr/local/Caskroom*

**Homebrew Cask Taps**: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-cask (3823 casks)

/usr/bin/xattr

2. `brew cleanup`
3. `brew update`
4. `brew tap mongodb/brew`
   [Mongo Docs installation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/)
5. `brew install mongodb-community@4.4`

Already downloaded: /Users/kevinturney/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/269692f6b2d908000ecd7602021f4826947a782576c1fea760d25ece5ccbb521--mongodb-macos-x86_64-4.4.3.tgz

6. `brew services start mongodb-community@4.4`

Service `mongodb-community` already started, use `brew services restart mongodb-community` to restart.

7. `brew services restart mongodb-community`

==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)

==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)

8. kevinturney / $ `brew services list`

Here is the error:

| Name | Status | User | Plist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mongodb-community | **error** | kevinturney | /Users/kevinturney/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist |
| mysql | stopped |  |  |
| postgresql | stopped |  |  |
| redis | stopped |  |  |
| unbound | stopped |  |  |

I checked the processes,

[MongDB University-processes](https://university.mongodb.com/mercury/M103/2021_February_9/chapter/Chapter_0_Introduction_Setup/lesson/5eaafca87c4bdbe505e9ca5f/lecture)

9. `ps -ef | grep mongo`

501 10770 81999   0 10:34AM ttys007    0:00.00 grep mongo

10. `ps -ef | grep mongod`

501 10776 81999   0 10:34AM ttys007    0:00.00 grep mongod

11. `ps -ef | grep mongos`

01 10781 81999   0 10:34AM ttys007    0:00.00 grep mongos

12. `mongo --version`

MongoDB shell version v4.2.2
git version: a0bbbff6ada159e19298d37946ac8dc4b497eadf
allocator: system
modules: enterprise 
build environment:
distarch: x86_64
target_arch: x86_64

13. `mongod --version`

db version v4.2.2
git version: a0bbbff6ada159e19298d37946ac8dc4b497eadf
allocator: system
modules: enterprise 
build environment:
distarch: x86_64
target_arch: x86_64

When I run  `brew services start mongodb-community` it successfully starts and then

`mongo` this is the result:

```
kevinturney / $ brew services start mongodb-community

==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)

kevinturney / $ mongo

MongoDB shell version v4.2.2<br/>
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb<br/>
2021-02-17T11:37:32.192-0500 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, <br/>connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:341:17<br/>
@(connect):2:6
2021-02-17T11:37:32.195-0500 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2021-02-17T11:37:32.195-0500 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

I followed a very similar [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184438/problem-using-and-running-brew-services-start-mongodb-community4-2), went though mongo docs, [uninstalled](https://medium.com/@rajanmaharjan/uninstall-mongodb-macos-completely-d2a6d6c163f9), reinstalled, Also, [tried this great post](https://medium.com/@saiankit30/setting-up-mongodb-on-macos-catalina-common-errors-and-their-solutions-72fd66fb8a86) I am not sure what to try next.

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I'm facing the same issue. mongodb-community@3.6 works great but I cannot manage to get mongodb-community@4.0 service running

Comment: Ok, I've dumped all my databases, removed the mongodb data folder and reinstalled mongodb@4. After that the mongodb@4 service started successfully and I could restore all my dumps. Not the way it was supposed to upgrade my mongo version but finally it worked.

Comment: Now I have the same trouble how to resolve it?

Comment: You may try https://stackoverflow.com/a/68699846/6172369
The problem is with permissions of files due to OS upgrade to one of the newer MacOS versions. You can check mongod logs for more complete logs. Look for "Permission Denied".

Comment: Please look at this official installation guide https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Answer (score 31):

If you are using macOS Catalina / BigSur Above this fix will work:

Go to command line and execute these commands, you need to use SUDO else this will not work.

We first remove the folder mongodb,

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/var/mongodb
```

then, we add it manually,

```
cd /usr/local/var && mkdir mongodb
```

Now, we run the brew service as below, please mention the mongodb version at the end, as below:

```
brew services start mongodb-community@5.0
```

If you get below response please restart the service,

```
Service `mongodb-community` already started, use `brew services restart mongodb-community` to restart.
```

To restart the service use below, please mention the mongodb version at the end:

```
brew services restart mongodb-community@5.0

Stopping `mongodb-community`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-commu
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-commu
```

Now we list all services, with below command:

```
brew services list
```

Output:

```
Name              Status  User       Plist
mongodb-community started xxx         homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

Open your Terminal and type `mongod –version` to verify your installation.

Comment: this will delete any existing databases, the issue is with permissions of the data folder /usr/local/var/mongodb which can be fixed using chmod and chown commands.

Comment: works. thanks for giving me a chance to clean up unused DBs without thinking too deeply about it.

Comment: @zaffer could you elaborate?

Comment: @Akash you may refer to my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62184438/problem-using-and-running-brew-services-start-mongodb-community4-2

~ cd /usr/local/var/mongodb
~ sudo chown -R $(whoami) .
~ cd ..
~ sudo chown -R $(whoami) mongodb
~ brew services restart mongodb-community

~ chmod -R 777 /usr/local/var/mongodb
~ brew services restart mongodb-community

use sudo if required.

Comment: For those on an M1 mac, do this for the `/opt/homebrew/var` folder instead of `/usr/local/var`.

Comment: Bro, I've waste 6hours looking for solution. After this simple removal it works. MANY THANKS!

Comment: This happened to me after installed the latest / newest version of mongodb. Alternatively, we can use "mongod --dbPath=/another/directory" but be sure to use "mongod --version" 5.0

Answer (score 4):

Could be permission issues Check ownership of /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock Try to remove this file and start the service again

via:https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/help-brew-mongodb-community-5-0-error-macos/125648

Comment: This was the issue/solution for me. Thank you.