# error starting mongodb with brew start on macOS Catalina 10.15.6

Tags: mongodb, command-line, terminal, homebrew

I have tried a few troubleshoots to no avail. They don't seem to match my specific error. I start mongodb with

```
> brew services start mongodb-community
```

The terminal says it is succesfully started, but when i

```
> brew services
```

to check mongodb's status it says error. No explanation.
But if I open up a new terminal and run mongo, I do however get a more detailed error.

```
> connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/? 
> compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
> Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection 
> attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 
> 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to this problem. The socket exception error is apparently being thrown because the root owns the

```
/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

solution

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

re start mongodb with

```
brew services start mongodb-community@4.4
```

it will create a new

```
/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

which is owned by user. You can check by

```
ls -lsah /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

my output was then

```
0 srwx------  1 userName  wheel     0B Apr  8 12:05 /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

where username was previously root.

my solution was found here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62196227/15311479